# Having Problem using math environment in LuaLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, luatex, fontspec, kpfonts

I am at learning stage of LaTeX. While working with `lualatex` with `fontspec` package, i am not being able to use any math environment. My document's preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{memoir} %

\usepackage{amsmath} %Never write a paper without using amsmath for its many new commands
\usepackage{amssymb} %Some extra symbols

\usepackage{makeidx} %If you want to generate an index, automatically
\usepackage{graphicx} %If you want to include postscript graphics 
\usepackage{microtype} %
\usepackage{cleveref} %
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % font encoding
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=2cm]{geometry} % geometry/margins of page
\usepackage{multicol}       % multicolumn environments
\usepackage{tikz}           % used for the 'logo' (remove if unwanted)
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc, blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setSingleSpace{1.1}
\SingleSpacing

\definecolor{MSBlue}{RGB}{0, 85, 255}
\definecolor{MSLightBlue}{RGB}{42, 127, 255}
\definecolor{WaterBlue}{RGB}{0, 212, 255}
\definecolor{RHlight}{RGB}{255, 170, 0}

% %setting section style
\newfontfamily\sectionFont{Interstate BoldCondensed} %
\newfontfamily\emphFont{Bell MT Bold}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sectionFont\color{MSBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sectionFont\color{MSLightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\sectionFont}

% %setting enumeration style
\setlist[description]{font=\bfseries, labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*} %
\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=\parindent} %

\definecolor{chaptercolor}{gray}{0.8}
% helper macros
\setmainfont{Cambria}
```

Whenever I use `$...$` inside of begin{document}, I am having the following error:

```
miktex-makepk: / is an unknown METAFONT mode.
Process exited with error(s)
```

I have tried with `no-math` option with `fontspec` package and using `unicode-math` package but it seems it is conflicting with `kpfonts` package and giving following error:

```
Command `\mathscr' already defined. ...}{U}{jkp\kp@famillem syd\kp@widerm}{m}{n}
```

Using `mathspec` package is giving following error:

```
Undefined control sequence {\relax}
```

So, my questions are:

1. why actually I am having these error.
2. how can I work with math environment by keeping `fontspec` and `kpfonts` package?

Comment: You can't use `unicode-math` with `kpfonts`, this is for sure, but also using `kpfonts` and `fontspec` opens a can of worms, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `kpfonts` with `fontspec` and `unicode-math`. These fonts exist only in Type1 format for `pdflatex`.